# Probability of K repetitions of a number when throwing M-sided N dices

Tags: probability, statistics

I would like to know the equation that describes the probability of getting $K$ repetitions of any number when throwing $N$ dices of $M$ faces.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think i got the answer. $N$ is the total number of dice, $K$ the repetitions and $M$ the sides.

The probability is:

$$ P(K) =\binom{n}{k}\frac{(m-1)^{n-k}}{m^n}$$

Edit:

Ok ok, but what about generalizing more the problem? Lets say that instead of one number of $K$ repetitions we have several groups of repeated numbers and we want to calculate the probability. If $S$ is the number of groups, each with is own $K_i$ I think the equation could be something like this:

$$ \left(\prod_{i=1}^{S} \binom{\sum_{j=i}^{S}k_j}{k_i}\right)\binom{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{S}k_i}\frac{(m-S)^{(n-\sum_{i=1}^{S}k_i)}}{m^n}$$

What do you think?

For now I think I will go to bed, for some reason this solution came to mind while I was about to fall asleep, so I haven't checked if it makes sense. I might check this again tomorrow. Feel free to comment.

Comment: Your reasoning?

Comment: You can think of 1 repetition as chosing one element from the group of dice, 2 as chosing 2 and so on. The number of combinations for this is the binomial. Now, once we have fixed the repetitions the number of times each repetition combination appears depends on the rest of the dice (n-k). Those dice cant have the same number, so instead of m they are m-1 type dice. Divide that by all the possible combinations, m^n.

Comment: Sorry not 1 repetition and 2 repetitions, a 'repetition' of only 1 element and a 'repetition' with 2 elements.

Comment: The binomial gives the number of ways of selecting k elements from a group of n.